# ifelse() gave me wrong output

Tags: r, if-statement

I got a data.frame named DF1

```
Digit   Country
1       A
1       B
2       C
16      China P Rep
15      Indonesia
```

i'm using `DF1$Digit <- ifelse(DF1$Digit<=5,"",DF1$Digit)` it become

```
Digit   Country
        A
        B
        C
16      China P Rep
15      Indonesia
```

after that i uses `DF1$Country2 <- ifelse(DF1$Digit== "","",DF1$Country)`
For some reason the output is

```
Digit   Country       Country2
        A         
        B             
        C          
16      China P Rep     36        
15      Indonesia       80
```

I doesn't know what's the problem here.. Hope someone could help me

Comment: Some thoughts: (1) it will help us to help you if we see more info about the data, as shown with the output of `dput(DF1)`, things that the current representation does not show. (2) `ifelse` should always have the same class of data in the 2nd/3rd arguments, so if it returns `character` in one, then it should return `character` in the other; problems with disparity here are motivators for `dplyr::if_else` where this is strictly enforced. In this case, you will (unintentionally?) convert `$Digit` to a character.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Works fine for me as long as `Country` is a character and not a factor variable:

```
DF1 <- data.frame(
    Digit = c(1,1,2,16,15),
    Country = c("A", "B", "C", "China", "Indonesia"),
    stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)

DF1$Digit <- ifelse(DF1$Digit<=5,"",DF1$Digit)

DF1$Country2 <- ifelse(DF1$Digit== "","",DF1$Country)

DF1
```

Output:

```
  Digit   Country  Country2
1               A          
2               B          
3               C          
4    16     China     China
5    15 Indonesia Indonesia
```

You can check if `Country` is a factor variable with `str(DF1)` or simply `is.factor(DF1$Country)`.  If it is a factor variable, you can convert it to character like so:

```
DF1$Country <- as.character(DF1$County)
```